# Not getting JSON data in Parameters of Actions On google(Google Assistant)..?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image: This is my image of Intent]`app.body_.result.parameters` in this object structure I am getting user Selected data or user said data in webhook cloud function when I am running it in Api.ai/DialogFlow console as,

```
app.body_.result.parameters{
  drink:RedBull,
  pizzaname:Chicken Pizza
}
```

but when I ran same intent for ‘Google Assistant’ above JSON object is returned as blank…

```
app.body_.result.parameters{
  drink: ,
  pizzaname:
}
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Please update your question to include screen shots of the intent as shown in Dialogflow, and a sample of how you are triggering the intent from the Google Assistant and from Dialogflow.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated my question with my intent snapshot..

Comment: Can you go into details about what **exactly** you're doing to trigger the intent that doesn't give any results? Are you sure this is the intent that is triggered - is this the intent name that is sent to your fulfillment?

Comment: 1) to invoke this 'lastIntent' or before this 'lastIntent', their is another intent in which their is carousal list of drinks from which user selects any drink.. However, response of drinks carousal list is chip which is mentioned in UserSays section of 'lastIntent'.. hence, 'lastIntent' is triggered.                   2) well I havent explicitly sent 'lastIntent' name to fullfillment..          really want solve this problem ASAP.. @Prisoner